# ajax set headers for basic authorization does not work

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, cors, basic-authentication

Here is my code,I want to request a cross domain url to use API based on basic authorization.

but it does not work. no Authorization info showed in request headers.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'Authorization': "Basic amlhemhc6SUxvdmVAkYXk="),
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        }
    });
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "http:localhost:8080/query",
        type: "POST",
        data: '{"sql":"select count(*) from summary"}',
        dataType: "json"
    });
    request.done(function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    });

    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Kind of unrelated but please don't use strings for JSON objects. Use `JSON.stringify({'sql': ....})` instead!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax

Comment: Did you get this worin?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following callbacks to your `$.ajax()`:

```
var request = $.ajax({
        url: "http:localhost:8080/query",
        type: "POST",
        data: '{"sql":"select count(*) from summary"}',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        processData: 'false',
        xhrFields: {
              withCredentials: 'true'
        },
        crossDomain: 'true'
    });
```

Comment: to support cors domain request,I add Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* in the response.because of which .when I modify as you suggested ,throw error like this( A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.)

Comment: have you tried entering the exact domain instead of using `*`? Since we are using credentials, you will get this error as it is a part of security. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:your domain`

Comment: yes ,but still response 401 status code.and no field Authorization in the Request Headers,it's supposed there.

Answer (score 0):

your ajax should look something like this, if it still doesnt work then you can take a look one of my post about CORS [here](http://aameer.github.io/articles/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors/) and see what issue you are facing

```
ajaxOpts = {
        url:"https://"+server_name+"/post_link/",
        crossDomain:true,
        xhrFields: {withCredentials:true},
        type:'POST',
        data: jQuery('#some_form').serialize(),//or your data
        dataType:'json',
        success: {
            //do something
        },
        error: {
            //do something
        },
    };
    jQuery.ajax(ajaxOpts);
```

hope it helps